# Margin top isn't working in IE8 but works in all other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, margin

I have a button and an arrow image placed over the button. The CSS is written so as to position the arrow in the right center of the button. The code works fine for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Also it works fine in IE9 and other higher versions. But does not work in IE8 specifically and most of our clients use IE8. The CSS is given below.

```
a.ui-priority-primary-inspire span.arr-right {
background: url("/cms/global/assets/images/site/icon_vsg/arr_right_7x11.png") no-repeat scroll right top hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
display: block;
float: right;
height: 17px;
margin: -14px -9px 4px 79px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 10px;
}
```

`margin-top:-14px` works in all browsers but not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-top` instead. Reference : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/margin-top

Answer (score 0):

That is called **[Negative Margin Bug](http://www.trickyclicks.com/web-coding/css/negative-margin-for-ie7-ie8.html)** As you are using `position:absolute` you could use `top:-14px` instead of using `negative margin` value.

Comment: It is again yielding the same result :(

Comment: This is actually a complex application. There are around 6 different css files that are put together. I guess I couldn't post the entire code here as such.